# Django - Heroku - Serving dynamic large file timing out

Tags: python, django, heroku, large-data

I have one function view that creates a report using xlsxwriter, it is created on the fly using a StringIO as buffer and finally sending through HttpResponse. 
It works well using Local Server.

The problem is that on Heroku, after some seconds (documentation mention 30 seconds timeout and not modifiable) the server hangs out and reboot the web process, giving error as a response.

**What is the best way to...?**:

- create an xmlx file on the fly (dynamically) in memory
- serve the entire file to the client.
- prevent server to hang out because of the long process running

This is a piece of the code I am using:

```
def reporte_usuarios(request):
    from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
    try:
        import cStringIO as StringIO
    except ImportError:
        import StringIO

    # create a workbook in memory
    output = StringIO.StringIO()

    workbook = Workbook(output)

    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

    # get the data
    from django.db.models import Count
    usuarios = User.objects.filter(....... # all filter stuff

    for usr in usuarios:
        if usr.activos > 0:

            # create a workbook sheet every User registered
            ws = workbook.add_worksheet(u'%s' % usr.username)

            # some relevant user data
            ws.write(1, 1, u'USUARIO: %s' % usr.username)
            ...

            # get rows for user
            log = LogActivos.objects.filter(usuario=usr).select_related('activo__unidad__id', 'activo__unidad__nombre', 'activo__nombre')

            # write headers
            ws.write(3, 0, u'FECHA', bold)
            ...
            sig_fila = 4  #starting row for data (after headers)
            for l in log:
                # write all data
                ws.write(sig_fila, 0, u'%s' % l.fecha)
                ...
                sig_fila += 1
    # close the workbook
    workbook.close()
    # go to the beginning of the buffer
    output.seek(0)
    # response using the buffer
    response = HttpResponse(output.read(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="ACTIVOS_USUARIOS__%s.xlsx"' % datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M")
    return response
```

Notes: I am using Gunicorn on Heroku, django 1.9.13 and python 2.7.11

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should follow a totally different approach in this case.
As you are generating a file rather big in size, it's normal for the system to hang out because of a timeout error.

What you could do instead is to deploy a background task queue, like Celery or DjangoRQ. With that, you will get a background task to create this file using your user's data, and then you can let your user know that it's ready by any mean, like a notification or an email.

If you need more details regarding how you can do something like this, let me know and I can help :)

Comment: I have been working in a background process using Celery and Redis, that creates the file and saves it in temporary dir, then it serves the file when it is ready and notifies the user. but the part of making it run in Heroku is a pain. do you have any kind of guide to do this?

Comment: Is there a specific part you've stuck? Just be a bit more precise regarding what kind of info do you need and I'll have a look around for guides regarding similar cases

Comment: I have now all the background job working nice with redis and celery, but I am saving my archive in Amazon S3 and returning the URL to the user to start the download. This is working but is not what I want, because I need to make the archive temporary or generate it in memory, and everything in a worker or background process.

Comment: well, a workaround for that would be to delete the file from S3 after a short period of time, for example, 2hours. Would that work better for you?

Comment: Yeah! it would be nice! but, should I need more heroku workers to do that? or what is the way to create that "timer delete"?

Comment: It depends on your app design. If you have a Django model that keeps track of the files generated for the users and the timestamp it created them, then you can use a Celery scheduled task to run after 2h and delete this file from S3 along with the model instance (or set it to a "deleted" status or something like that). Have a look here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html and here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.schedules.html. Let me know if you need further help!